# Does Python have something similar to .net c# PInvoke?

Tags: python, pinvoke

Do CPython has something similar to .net c# PInvoke?

For example I have some.dll or some.so and would like to register some functions from it on runtime and start using those in my program.

In C# you can do:

```
// Marshal.cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CSharpIterators
{
    class MainClass
    {
        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
        public static extern int puts([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string m);

        [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")]
        internal static extern int _flushall();

        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {

            puts("Hello World!");
            _flushall();
        }
    }
}
```

Do python has similar functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call functions from DLLs using Python's [`ctypes` module](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use tools like swig in order to create a Python interface to C/C++ code:
http://www.swig.org/

The syntax for creating the wrappers is very similar to C plus some preprocessing directives.